# How do I address files in Asset folder?

Tags: android, assets

I need to read "strings.json" file that lies in the "assets" folder of my Android project. But

```
File file = new File(filepath);
Logger.e(file.exists() ? "exists" : "doesn't exist");
```

says that the file doen't exist. I've tried the following variants of the filepath:

- strings.json
- android_asset/strings.json
- /android_asset/strings.json
- file:///android_asset/strings.json

What's wrong?

Comment: You need to use getAssets() from within an activity. Have a look at this: https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/store-and-use-files-in-assets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For read files in Assets:

```
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("strings.json");

        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        is.read(buffer);

        is.close();

        fileResult = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
```

In `fileResult` you should retrieve the content of your file.

Answer (score 0):

```
 AssetManager manager = getAssets();
        try {
            InputStream stream = manager.open(string+".xml");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```